# Bitbucket Pipeline read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a staging server and a production server, and I run identical Bitbucket Pipelines, where I send some commands over SSH. Unfortunately, my pipeline for the production always fails with:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

I've tried *everything*, folder permissions, recreating the keys, nothing works.

Finally with adding `-v` to my `ssh` call, I think I'm a step closer, but still lost.

On my staging server, I see something like this:

```
debug1: Host '$STAGING_SERVER' is known and matches the RSA host key.   
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4   
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
```

and the rest of the build follows flawlessly.

On my production server, however, I see the following:

```
debug1: Host '$PRODUCTION_SERVER' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

So it would look like the key *is* found on my production server, but for some reason on the production server `read_passphrase` is being called. I've just created a new id_rsa and id_rsa.pub key, with *no* password, so why the heck is my production server trying to call `read_passphrase`? My `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` on both servers are identical - checked via `diff`.

Another way of looking at it is that `ssh_rsa_verify` is called immediately on the staging server, while on the production server `read_passphrase` is called.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Hi, is /dev/tty exists and accessible in your production server? Can you compare /dev/tty setup for both servers? Also, are your servers using the same SSH key to connect? If not, is your production SSH key structurally fine?  Can you also check this?

Comment: So /dev/tty does not exist on either server - but as you can see in the staging server, it's not even being checked, so I shouldn't need to have it. I have a feeling this is some sort of SSH setting calling `read_passphrase` but I'm not sure which one - as I mentioned the `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` are identical (I just double checked with `diff`), is there any other settings file I should check?

Comment: As for the SSH keys, they are different, but the production one is just newly generated so I assume it's valid...

Comment: There is one more thing comes my mind is maybe you can try to set `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` in the production, also, to go beyond the assumption, maybe you can try to assign newly created production ssh key to staging as well and try to connect with it just to make sure there is no problem in the validity perspective.

Comment: Then I'm worried I'll lose the working flow in staging :). But I will try this `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Comment: If you are using a cloud provider, you can create an image from your staging server, so your all configuration will be copied, and after that you can work on it :) Okay, hit me with the result via this thread whether it's solved or not.

Comment: Still not working, I'm going to contact the server admin on why this is happening, something is surely wrong with the configuration at this point.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm out of ideas, please let me know about the root cause of the problem :)

Comment: I've also posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681280/read-passphrase-being-called-on-ssh-key-even-though-ssh-key-is-not-protected-by?noredirect=1#comment1287365_681280 but seems also nobody has an idea :)

Comment: @OguzhanAygun - just got it, thanks for your help and ideas over the past few days 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hallelujah! Solved!**

Hours wasted for the simplest reason...

I noticed in the full output of the `ssh -v` on production that Bitbucket was printing out something like this:

```
debug1: Connecting to $PRODUCTION_SERVER [12.345.567.890] port 22.
```

where as the staging output was:

```
debug1: Connecting to $STAGING_SERVER [$STAGING_SERVER] port 22.
```

Meaning the static IP *was* the exact value of that repository variable. (Bitbucket parses secret logs out, which is why they appear this way).

I realized I had set the repository variable `PRODUCTION_SERVER` incorrectly to the *alias* for the IP address, (i.e. `myserver.com`) when it should be the IP address exactly. Changing that value in my repository variables to the IP address fixed the issue! Apparently, using the alias name isn't a perfect enough match for SSH to be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved this problem by

1. go to -> Repository settings
2. go to -> SSH keys ( on the left navigation)
3. at the known hosts section

- input your Bastion host public IP address
- then click Fetch button
- rerun your pipeline

[Please check this for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8G0H.png)